# Как задать оглавление при печати страницы?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css3

Я использую [bootstrap-toc](https://afeld.github.io/bootstrap-toc/) для определения заголовка(h1, h2, h3) и он мне возвращает заголовок в таком виде

```
<nav>
 <ul>
   <li>
    <a>Test</a>
   </li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Мне нужно чтобы при печати заголовок преобразовался как в Word - после названия заголовка точки до конца строки и номер страницы:

[image]

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать это ? Нашел [статью](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-gcpm-3/#funcdef-target-counter) (см.Раздел 5 Cross-references), но у меня оно не работает. Помогите пожалуйста.